# How to pass paramters by refrence in ant

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Hi all this is my code for target calling.

```
<target name="abc">
  <var name="x" value="10"/>
  <antcall target="def"/>
  <!--Again Access The value of x here and also change it here-->
</target>

<target name="def">
  <!--Access The value of x here and also change it here-->
</target>
```

and also i want to access this X in other build file,is there any way

Comment: What is `var`?  I don't recognise any Ant task by that name.

Comment: it is variable task in ant and is used for creating variables in ant

Comment: @skaffman it is from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: you can [accept answers that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160062) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with ant. In an properties are immutable and cannot be reset. The [var task from ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) can be used to override values, but should be used sparingly.

You could use a temporary file to achieve what you want. But probably you are trying something weird, which can be solved in a different way.
This would also work across buildfiles if they have access to the property file.

```
<target name="abc">
  <var name="x" value="10"/>
  <antcall target="def"/>
  <!--Again Access The value of x here and also change it here-->
  <var unset="true" file="myproperty.properties" /> <!-- read variable from property file-->
</target>


<target name="def">
  <echo file="myproperty.properties" append="false">x=12</echo> <!-- create a new propertyfile-->
</target>
```

Comment: `echoproperties` and `loadproperties` ant task may be used to store and load file with temp prop values. `prefix` attribute of `loadproperties` sometimes helps to overcome issue of property immutability.

Comment: @Vadzim this prefix stuff sounds more hacky than my var approach :) but echoproperties is a good hint

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of justice, there is a hack that allows to alter ant's immutable properties without any additional libs (since java 6):

```
<scriptdef name="propertyreset" language="javascript"
    description="Allows to assing @{property} new value">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="value"/>
        project.setProperty(attributes.get("name"), attributes.get("value"));
</scriptdef>
```

Usage:

```
<target name="abc">
    <property name="x" value="10"/>
    <antcall target="def"/>
</target>

<target name="def">
    <propertyreset name="x" value="11"/>
</target>
```

As @oers mentioned, this should be used with care after all canonical approaches proved not to fit.

It is difficult to suggest further without knowing the goal behind the question.

Comment: will this "survive" the return from antcall, i.e. is x = 11 after the antcall? This is what op asked.

Comment: This is just a complementary partial answer. I guess similar scripting approach can even be used to access parent project's props. The question is not very clean btw.